# angular ui routing : avoid refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For the given ui-route

```
    .state('index.m', {
        url: "m{path:.*}",
        views: {
            "viewContainer": {
                templateUrl: "p/m.html"
            }
        }
```

I want to avoid refresh of template if i am at /m and want to move to /m/a or /m/a/b

with the following code : `$location.path('m/a')`

Comment: you can use $state.go

Comment: Besides `$state.go` you'll need to split your page in multiple views + controllers so that the common ones don't reload.

Comment: Error: Could not resolve 'm/123' from state 'index.m'. for both   url: "m{path:.*}", OR   url: "m"